# import and plot data from multiple files without too many lines

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I wrote a code that imports columns from a text file and plots them like this:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset = np.genfromtxt(fname='filename.dat')
x=dataset[:,3]  # column select
y=dataset[:,2] 

plt.semilogx()
#plt.semilogy()
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title ('title')

plt.plot(x, y, color='red', linewidth=1)  
plt.show()
```

The problem is that I would plot many more filename.dat (always columns 3 and 2 in every filename.dat).
At the moment I have 23 filename.dat that I would like to plot all together in the same plot. These filename.dat are named as:

```
filename01.dat
filename02.dat
...
filename23.dat
```

I know I could rewrite the lines:

```
dataset_ = np.genfromtxt(fname='filename_.dat')
x_=dataset_[:,3] 
y_=dataset_[:,2]
# where '_' is the number of each filename.dat
plt.plot(x_, y_, color='red', linewidth=1)
```

For each filename.dat, but is there a faster and more practical way (with np.genfromtxt and put.plot) to not rewrite the same lines for 23 times?

UPDATE: I would also like a different color for each file.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop. Make sure to initialise your figure before the loop if you want to plot all 23 lines on the same axis:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

filenames = os.listdir(your_path) # get a list of filenames

fig, ax = plt.subplots()    # create a figure

for file in filenames:
    dataset = np.genfromtxt(file)

    x=dataset[:,3]  # column select
    y=dataset[:,2]

    ax.plot(x, y)

ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_xlabel("x")
ax.set_ylabel("y")

plt.show()
```

If you remove `color =` in your `ax.plot()` then matplotlib should automatically change the color of each line for you. However, as @jack6e suggested in the comments, in order to plot your own colours, you can create a list (`c_list`) with the colours in it and then do:

```
for i, file in enumerate(filenames):   
    # your code

    ax.plot(x, y, color=c_list[i])
```

Comment: You should use glob for collecting the exact files: `import glob` then `glob.glob('filename*.dat')`.

Comment: You can create a `color_palette`, but I don't know if you can get 23 colors out of any of the defaults. If you know what colors you want you can generate a `list` of 23 colors and then use `for i, file in enumerate(filenames)`, so that you can select the relative color from that list within your loop as `color = color_list[i]`, and then pass that color to your plot command.

Comment: thanks! here there is a list of all color if you want: https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/named_colors.html

Comment: This (the first post without a loop for colors) give me an error: 
`IOError: filename01.dat not found.`

Comment: You need to be in the same directory as your files `os.chdir(your_path)`